# I am installing Angular12 and i am experiencing the below errs pls what can i do. does it have to do with the window version?

Tags: angular, command, window, new-operator, angular12

```
- Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: youtube@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@12.2.0-next.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~12.2.0-next.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^12.0.0 || ^12.1.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.0-next.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~12.2.0-next.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Politics17\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Politics17\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-02T05_47_00_003Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Comment: did you try the command along with --force or --legacy-peer-deps ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when updating my node version to 12. The solution was run:

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

If you don't want to run `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` every time, you can add `legacy-peer-deps=true` in your npm configuration file (.npmrc in the project root, if it doesn't exist you can create it).

Information about [legacy-peer-deps](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

This can also be set more permanently as a configuration option like this:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

However, if above approach does not work try removing the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then run this command:

```
npm install
```